# Сделать выборку JQuery

Tags: jquery, dom

Всем привет. Задача следующая.
Имеется страница с некоторым числом поп-апов (с одинаковым классом), содержащих разные формы.
Внутри каждой формы есть пустой

```
<div id="result"></div>
```

который будет получать и выводить ответ сервера после отправки формы. Сами формы, по сути, идентичные, только разные поля.
Как правильно сделать выборку, чтоб при сабмите ответ выводился именно в #result, находящийся в форме, которую отправил юзер, а не в первом попавшемся на странице?

скрипт сабмита:

```
$('.formAjax').submit(function(event) {

    /* отключение стандартной отправки формы */
    event.preventDefault();

    /* собираем данные с элементов страницы: */
    var $form = $( this ),
        h1_form = $('h1').text(),
        h2_form = $('h2').text(),
        link = $form.find( 'input[name="url"]' ).val(),
        ajax = $form.find( 'input[name="ajax"]' ).val(),
        name = $form.find( 'input[name="name"]' ).val(),
        phone = $form.find( 'input[name="phone"]' ).val(),
        diapazon = $form.find( 'select[name="diapazon"]>option' ).val(),
        url = $form.attr( 'action' );


    /* отправляем данные методом POST */
    var posting = $.post( url, { h1: h1_form,  h2: h2_form, url: link, ajax: ajax, name: name, phone: phone, diapazon: diapazon } );

    /*после отправки формы*/
    posting.done(function( data ) {

      /*выводим результат запроса*/
      // alert( data );
      // alert('Вы записались на прием, мы скоро свяжемся с вами');
      // $('form').html(result);
      // $( "#result" ).empty().append( data );
      $( "#result" ).text(data);
      console.log ('ok');


      /*очищаем поля формы*/
      $(':input','form')
          .not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden')
          .val('')
          .removeAttr('checked')
          .removeAttr('selected');
    });
});
```

пример формы

```
<form action="/algo/addappointment.php" class="formAjax">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Ваше имя*" name="name" required class="form__input form__input_popup"/>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Телефон*" name="phone" required class="form__input form__input_popup"/>
          <input type="hidden" name="url" required value="<?=$APPLICATION->GetCurDir()?>"/>
          <input type="hidden" name="h1" required id="h1_form" value=""/>
          <input type="hidden" name="ajax" required value="y"/>           
          <select name="diapazon" class="form__input form__input_popup">
            <option value="9-12">С 9 до 12</option>
            <option value="12-15">С 12 до 15</option>
            <option value="15-18">С 15 до 18</option>
            <option value="18=21">С 18 до 21</option>                   
          </select>
          <input type="submit" value="Записаться" class="button button_big"/>
          <div id="result"></div>
        </form>
```

Comment: У вас что id div на всех формах одинаковый? Атрибут id — уникальное имя элемента, которое используется для изменения его стиля и обращения к нему через скрипты. Идентификатор в коде документа должен быть в единственном экземпляре, иными словами, встречаться только один раз.

Comment: да, div для вывода ответа, допустим, это не айди, а класс. как быть?

Comment: Каждому своему div присваивайте индивидуальный id, в последствии - обрабатывайте.

Comment: @Ishutinov, т.е. вы хотите сказать, что для данной модели невозможно провести выборку?

Comment: добавь в вопрос примеры форм, и как делается submit

Comment: @Grundy готово.

Comment: @wannaBpro, я не чего не хочу сказать. О какой выборке вы пишите, если нет конкретных примеров вашего кода. Я вам привел общую информацию о атрибуте, который вы используете.

Comment: _добавь в вопрос примеры форм_ - примеры разметки самих форм

Comment: @Grundy добавил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка в самой выборке

```
$( "#result" ).text(data);
```

Выборка производится в контексте все страницы. Для решения ее нужно производить в контексте формы, которая уже сохранена

```
var $form = $( this ),
```

Использовав, например метод *find*

```
form.find('#result').text(data);
```

Но id в данном случае лучше заменить на класс, так как из-за неуникальности id могут быть другие проблемы, например с применением стилей.

Пример:

```js
$('.formAjax').submit(function(event) {

  /* отключение стандартной отправки формы */
  event.preventDefault();

  /* собираем данные с элементов страницы: */
  var $form = $(this),
    h1_form = $('h1').text(),
    h2_form = $('h2').text(),
    link = $form.find('input[name="url"]').val(),
    ajax = $form.find('input[name="ajax"]').val(),
    name = $form.find('input[name="name"]').val(),
    phone = $form.find('input[name="phone"]').val(),
    diapazon = $form.find('select[name="diapazon"]>option').val(),
    url = $form.attr('action');


  /* отправляем данные методом POST */
  var posting = $.post(url, {
    h1: h1_form,
    h2: h2_form,
    url: link,
    ajax: ajax,
    name: name,
    phone: phone,
    diapazon: diapazon
  });

  /*после отправки формы*/
  posting.complete(function(data) {

    /*выводим результат запроса*/
    // alert( data );
    // alert('Вы записались на прием, мы скоро свяжемся с вами');
    // $('form').html(result);
    // $( "#result" ).empty().append( data );
    $form.find("#result").text(`Form ${$form.attr('id')}: Answer from server - ${JSON.stringify(arguments)}`);
    console.log('ok');


    /*очищаем поля формы*/
    $(':input', 'form')
      .not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden')
      .val('')
      .removeAttr('checked')
      .removeAttr('selected');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="/algo/addappointment.php" id="firstFrom" class="formAjax">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Ваше имя*" name="name" required class="form__input form__input_popup" />
  <input type="text" placeholder="Телефон*" name="phone" required class="form__input form__input_popup" />
  <input type="hidden" name="url" required value="<?=$APPLICATION->GetCurDir()?>" />
  <input type="hidden" name="h1" required id="h1_form" value="" />
  <input type="hidden" name="ajax" required value="y" />
  <select name="diapazon" class="form__input form__input_popup">
    <option value="9-12">С 9 до 12</option>
    <option value="12-15">С 12 до 15</option>
    <option value="15-18">С 15 до 18</option>
    <option value="18=21">С 18 до 21</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Записаться" class="button button_big" />
  <div id="result"></div>
</form>
<form action="/algo/addappointment.php" class="formAjax" id="secondFrom">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Ваше имя*" name="name" required class="form__input form__input_popup" />
  <input type="text" placeholder="Телефон*" name="phone" required class="form__input form__input_popup" />
  <input type="hidden" name="url" required value="<?=$APPLICATION->GetCurDir()?>" />
  <input type="hidden" name="h1" required id="h1_form" value="" />
  <input type="hidden" name="ajax" required value="y" />
  <select name="diapazon" class="form__input form__input_popup">
    <option value="9-12">С 9 до 12</option>
    <option value="12-15">С 12 до 15</option>
    <option value="15-18">С 15 до 18</option>
    <option value="18=21">С 18 до 21</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Записаться" class="button button_big" />
  <div id="result"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: прописать же нужно вместо моего $( "#result" ).text(data); ?
ответ так и не выводится в #result
даже обычная строка не записывается туда, в чём может быть проблема?

Comment: @wannaBpro, добавил в ответ пример. Проверь так же значение переменной, которое вставляешь, и ошибки в консоли, возможно просто ошибка запроса и ты не попадаешь в метод done

Comment: Спасибо! Теперь всё работает, консоль ошибок не выдавала, только .log выводился без ответа, видимо, что-то упустил изначально.

Answer (score 1):

На самом деле абсолютно не правильно делать несколько одинаковых id на одной странице. Это плохо.

Однако, если не хотите ничего переписывать в коде, а только найти правильный селектор, то внутри `$.submit()` он будет примерно такой: `$(this).find('#result')`

То есть вместо:

```
$("#result").empty().append(data);
```

Написать:

```
$(this).find('#result').empty().append(data);
```

Однако, настоятельно рекомендую вам исправить атрибут на класс (тогда в селекторе надо будет решетку сменить на точку, чтоб выбирался именно класс) `<div class="result"></div>` и проблема решиться, на мой взгляд.

Comment: тоже не прописывает никаких данных в # result почему-то

Comment: Сравните, пожалуйста, свой вариант с моим (https://jsfiddle.net/higimo/zhbkgsty/). Я не смогу сказать, в чём разница у вас.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ, воспользовался в итоге вариантом, предложенным выше